# Why is scrolling in Chromium super-smooth with Openbox but not with Compiz?

Tags: compiz, chromium, openbox

I have an extension for Chromium called Smooth-Scroll. While I use Openbox the scrolling is noticeably smooth with some thin ripples. Compiz is much more jerky. This is with Chromium 10; 11 hasn't dropped yet and is supposed to have accelerated layers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's just the way it us, hate to tell you but Ubuntu is getting heavy on resources. Just changed from 11.04/Unity on a brandnew netbook with Nvidias ION2 to Openbox & LXDE... it used to be like swimming with clothes on. I'm all OpenBox here after, it's mostly webbrowsing anyways...

Comment: It is getting heavy, I agree 100%.  I've been using openbox for years now, its the only WM for me.  The default setup loads you up, sky high, with unnecessary services.  Top the cake with a ton of python programs, most would have been written in C, years past.  the minimum requirements are misleading.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Chromium is still not using the smooth scrolling enabled by GTK3.4 yet.

The possibility is there, in fact, this simple Python examples shows a Webkit browser with smooth (not jump-by-a-few-lines) scrolling:

```
from gi.repository import WebKit as webkit
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk

view = webkit.WebView()

sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
sw.add(view)

win = gtk.Window()
win.add(sw)
win.show_all()

view.open("http://w3.org/")
gtk.main()
```

So the technology is in place, Chromium 22 just doesn't seem to use it yet.

Comment: Wow!! That is awesome! For all who haven't tried, just type in `python` into a terminal in Ubuntu and then copy and paste these commands. It's flawless. This demo (or similar) should be pointed to from any bugs or forums, etc. in response to any detractors *and* to demo exactly what "smooth scrolling" actually means in Ubuntu and GTK. Thanks for the demo.